# Reading File to Frameworks of Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I removed a file from the Framework section of my Xcode application and now I want to add the file back. However when I try to add the file back I get the following alert.

```
Could not copy /Users/brian/Downloads/iphone-exif-0-9.1(1)/Release-simulator-iphonesimulator/libiphone-exif.a to /Developer/CS193/GraffitiMap/libiphone-exif.a.
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a file in you project, you can either copy it in you project or just reference the file somewhere else on your hard drive.

When you removed the file from you project, you didn't remove it from you project folder. Xcode can't write at that path since there's already a file, and gives you an error.

Just remove the file that's already in your project folder from the Finder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to re-add the file that's already in the project folder?

Comment: @Richard Yes, that would work too. Depends if he want the new file or the old file in the project.

Comment: OP said "now I want to add the file back" which I took to mean the original file.

Comment: Yes, but also said "when I try to add the file back", so he has a newer copy or an other copy he wants to add.

Comment: it's not productive to argue, but he said "add the file back", not "add a different file".